# Admob Interstitial closes existing activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

When I display an Admob interstitial, it displays fine, and I have registered a listener to catch the onAdClosed event, but the problem is that I cannot actually do anything from that event that interacts with my UI because the interstitial has closed it all.

I'm creating the interstitial like this:

```
    storyAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    storyAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    storyAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            storyAd.loadAd(buildAdRequest());
            if (prevMusicPlaying) {
                toggleAudio();
            }
            loadNextPage();
        }
    });
    storyAd.loadAd(buildAdRequest());
```

I have it in my manifest too:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

The loadNextPage() call crashes because it tries to create a new fragment and add it to my activity, which it cannot do because the activity has been paused by the interstitial. So I just get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1328)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1346)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStack(FragmentManager.java:488)
```

How can I make it so that the InterstitialAd doesn't interfere in any way with the existing UI. It took a very long time to get the existing UI working with the various activity/fragment gotchas.

Comment: What you want to archive? Did you read description of `onAdClosed - Called when the user is about to return to the application after clicking on an ad.`

Comment: @Divers - What I'm trying to achieve is the ability to add an interstitial without messing up the existing extremely delicate Fragment system that I already have. So, ideally, I want to show an interstitial without pausing or closing the activity nor destroying any fragments that already exist. If I can't do that, then I at least need a callback that happens after the ad is closed but the user has already returned to the application, so I can update the UI without a crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is less than ideal but it works.

You update your data model in onAdClosed() but not anything related to the UI. Set a flag to indicate that the ad is closed or whatever you need to do.

Then in onResume() on the main Activity, you update the UI. You can check the flag from onAdClosed() or whatever and then update the GUI to reflect the new state.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably finishing the current activity before you are showing the interstitial and then relying on the interstitial callback to move to next page or screen for that matter

This is bad practice since you don't want your app flow to rely on the ad callbacks. there can be scenarios which an ad cant show at all

What you need to do is call

```
loadNextPage();
```

before you show an ad. when the ad will show it will simply go over the the app screen that way if there is an ad it will simply take over otherwise it will not effect the app